# declare html in jquery variable space error

Tags: php, jquery, forms

i populate form using jquery based on dropdown i have one drop down to handle number of people and number of walker i generate my html in div based on no of people selected but i have so many fields and i have taken them in variable but when i use space in html it shows an error so what is the alternative to this how should i generate my html using variable in for loop

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#num-people").change(function () {
        var countP = parseInt($("select#num-people option:selected").val());

        $("#walker option").each(function (index) {
            if (countP < index) {
                var newindex = index

                $("#walker option[value=" + newindex + "]").remove();
            }

        })
        for (var i = 1; i <= countP; i++) {
            $("#walker option[value=" + i + "]").remove();
            var j = i + 1;

            $('#walker').append(new Option('walker' + i, i));
            var walk = "#walker";
            var formhtml =
                "<div id=walker" + i + " style='display:none'>First Name:<input type='text' name='wname" + i + "' id='wname" + i + "'>Last Name:<input type='text' name='lname' id='lname'></div>";

            //generate waler if not exist
            if ($(walk + i).length == 0) {

                $('#form_div').append(formhtml);
            }
            //display walker                            
            $("#walker").change(function () {
                var numwalker = parseInt($("select#walker option:selected").val());

                $('#walker' + numwalker).css('display', 'block');
            })
        }
    })
});
</script>

<select name="num-people" id="num-people">
<option name="1">1</option>
<option name="2">2</option>
<option name="3">3</option>
<option name="4">4</option>
<option name="5">5</option>
<option name="6">6</option>
</select>

<select name="walker" id="walker">
<option value="">Select Walker</option>
</select>


<div id="form_div">

</div>
```

when i use html with space in variable it shows an error and i have many fields to mange then how to do this dynamically keeping varible value in div id etc..(using php code or using jquery but different way of generating html)

```
var formhtml=
"<div id=walker"+i+" style='display:none'>
First Name:<input type='text' name='wname"+i+"' id='wname"+i+"'>
Last Name:<input type='text' name='lname' id='lname'>
</div>";
```

Comment: your code seems to be working here

Comment: I notice there are a few JS lines that are not ended with ';'

Answer (score 0):

You can either close each line with `" +`, and open each line again `"`

```
var formhtml=
"<div id=walker"+i+" style='display:none'> " +
"First Name:<input type='text' name='wname"+i+"' id='wname"+i+"'> " +
"Last Name:<input type='text' name='lname' id='lname'> " +
"</div>";
```

or you can escape the line breaks with `\`

```
var formhtml=
"<div id=walker"+i+" style='display:none'> \
First Name:<input type='text' name='wname"+i+"' id='wname"+i+"'> \
Last Name:<input type='text' name='lname' id='lname'> \
</div>";
```

Comment: ok thanks but is there any way to generate this html,as i have so many fields is this good to take them in variable or is that other option?